# In “An element of a set can never be a subset of itself”, what does ‘itself’ stand for?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have just begun learning about sets. My first language isn't English. I'm in high school.

Here's an example problem I found in my textbook:

> **Example 11:** Let $A, B$ and $C$ be three sets. If $A∈B$ and
> $B⊂C$, is it true that $A⊂C$? If not, give an example.
>
> **Solution:** No. Let $A=\{1\}, B=\{\{1\}, 2\}$ and $C=\{\{1\}, 2, 3\}$. Here $A∈B$ as $A=\{1\}$ and $B⊂C$. But $A⊄C$ as $1∈A$ and $1∉C$.
>
> Note that an element of a set can never be a subset of itself.

[***The link to the textbook's chapter.***](https://ncert.nic.in/ncerts/l/kemh101.pdf)

What does “itself” stand for here? Does it mean an element of a set can't be it's own (the element's) subset?

Or does that mean an element cannot be both an element and a subset of a set at the same time?

If $P=\{p\}, Q=\{\{p\}, q\}$, and $R=\{\{p\}, q, r\}$, we can say that $P∈Q$. But, can we say that both $Q∈R$ and $Q⊂R$ are true? Is it so that $Q$ cannot be both an element and a subset of $R$? Is $\{\{p\}, q, r\}$ not the same as $\{p, q, r\}$?

Comment: Both are sensible... and both are false! The author is saying something that either makes no sense, or else is wrong.

Comment: I bet that the author here was thinking of the statement "A set cannot be a member of itself" (which follows, in ZFC, from the axiom of foundation) and got confused between "member" and "subset."

Comment: The only thing this makes me think of is the classical Barber's paradox by Bertrand Russel.
"The barber shaves everyone who don't shave themselves".
So does the barber shave himself?
To avoid allowing self references like this which create logical paradoxes.

Comment: @MiloBrandt: Unfortunately, that's not the reason. I know many textbooks that make all kinds of false or even nonsensical claims. The one quoted here is yet another to add to the list. Rishi, it is probably best to avoid that textbook if you want to study proper mathematics.

Comment: Note that, if $C = \{ 1, \{1\}, 2,3  \}$ then $A \in C$,  $A \subset C$, and $A \subseteq A$.

Comment: NCERT textbook, I bet!

Comment: @user21820 can you please remove the last sentence of your comment. I don't know how to explain but your comment would be misleading to many Indian students. The book which he is referring is from the publications which officially constitutes of most of the Indian exams but majority students dislike it because it is too basic and after getting an advice like "skip the book because they give wrong info" would be enough to make students skip these books.

Comment: @NipunKulshreshtha: **If a book is bad, then it is bad.** I will **not** censor myself so that students can be misled. If you want to do anything, write to the book author or publisher and get the **lousy book** improved. Whether some publication is related to Indian exams or not is also **irrelevant** to pedagogy. I care about students who want to learn, not about what people want to do in India.

Comment: @user21820 I don't know how to explain but it is a matter of many people's career and anyone who is studying that book is an Indian 11th grader(neither anyone who studies mathematics for REALLY LEARNING maths nor any non-Indian would read that). Please simply tell them to not believe in that part. And anyways, the whole book is not that wrong (1 -3 mistakes are still ok).

Answer (score 22):

Both interpretations are sensible. Unfortunately, both interpretations are false statements! That comment is just misguided. (It's not your fault; it's the author's fault)

For instance: your first interpretation is:

> If $A$ is a set, and $x\in A$ is an element of $A$, then $x$ cannot be a subset of $x$.

But that is false. In Set Theory, sets can be elements of other sets, and every set is a subset of itself. So $x$ can **certainly** be a subset of itself. For example, if $A=\{\{1\},\{2\}\}$, then $x=\{1\}$ is an element of $A$, and $x$ is a subset of itself.

Your second interpretation is:

> If $A$ is a set, and $x\in A$, then $x$ cannot be a subset of $A$.

But that is *also* false. In fact, there is a whole class of sets, known as "transitive set", with the property that *every* element is also a subset. For instance, the set $A=\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\}\}$, whose elements are (i) the empty set and (ii) the set whose only element is the empty set; has the property that each of its elements is, in addition to being an element of $A$, *also* a subset of $A$.

In short: I'm not sure what the author meant to say with that comment, but both natural interpretations of it are false.

---

What *is* true is that, in general, if $A$ is a set and $x\in A$ is an element of $A$, then you cannot say, from these facts alone, whether $x$ is a subset of $A$ or not; and if your set theory allows for objects that are not sets ("ur-elements"), then you may not know whether $x$ is a subset of itself or not.

It is also true that in many set theories, one cannot have a set be an element of itself: that is, you can never have $A\in A$. (But there *are* set theories where this is valid, however...)

Comment: I didn't get your explanation of his 2nd interpretation. If A= {1,2,{3,4},5}, will {3,4} be considered both an element and subset of A?

Comment: @NipunKulshreshtha: No, for $A=\{1,2,\{3,4\},5\}$, the set $\{3,4\}$ is an element but **not** a subset: neither $3$ nor $4$ are *elements* of $A$. In fact, $\{3,4\}$ is disjoint from $A$, in that $A\cap\{3,4\}=\varnothing$.  On the other hand, if $A=\{1,\{1\}\}$, then $\{1\}$ is both a subset and an element of $A$.

Answer (score 3):

It helps to think of the braces $\{\}$ as being quite literal. So if $P=\{p\}$, $Q=\{\{p\},q\}$, and $R=\{\{p\},q,r\}$, then:

- When we write $Q=\{\{p\},q\}$, it means that the set $Q$ contains the two elements $\{p\}$ and $q$. In symbols, $\{p\}\in Q$ and $q\in Q$. Since $P=\{p\}$, we can interchange those two things, so we can also write $P\in Q$.
- The statement "$P\subset Q$" means "any element of $P$ is an element of $Q$." Well, $p$ is an element of $P$, but **not** of $Q$.
- The set $R$ contains $\{p\}$, $q$, and $r$, and $Q$ contains $\{p\}$ and $q$. Thus, $Q\subset R$. However, $Q\notin R$, because $R$ does not contain the element $Q=\{\{p\},q\}$.

As someone pointed out, it is not true that if $x\in S$, then $x$ is not a subset of $S$, nor the similar statement that if $x\subset S$, then $x\notin S$. The set $\{1,\{1\}\}$ gives a counterexample to both. The only true statement I can think of here is that a set $S$ is never an element in itself. We can never have $S\in S$.

Answer (score 2):

"Itself" means the "set" here.
Example- A={a,b,c}
Therefore, according to the statement -"An element of a set can never be a subset of itself/the set.", a ⊄ A, b ⊄ A and c ⊄ A, which is true because a, b, c are the elements of A and not the subsets of A.

However, {a} ⊂ A, {b} ⊂ A, {c} ⊂ A, where the left hand side of "⊂" are some sets which has the element which is also present in A.

(Remember: A subset is that set whose elements are also present in another set(superset), so, because the elements are themselves not sets, so, they can't be subsets but the set of those element(s) can be a subset.)

Comment: if we modify the set $A = {{a},{b},{c},a,b,c} $